# ToolTip in ZedGraph refreshes continuously and uses a significant amount of CPU

Tags: winforms, zedgraph

I am using ZedGraph to show Japanese candles.  I set the GraphPane.isShowPointValue=true, but when I move my mouse on the candle, the tooltip is refreshing and refreshing.

I find that when the tooltip is shown, it always takes more than 50% CPU time.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into this, the patch described in this link might resolve the issue:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3061209&group_id=114675&atid=669144

Answer (score 3):

At this point there is a newer version of ZedGraph that fixes this problem.
currently v5.1.7
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZedGraph/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with application developed several years ago for Win XP when users started migration to Win 7.

The above mentioned path did not help me, so I wrote quick and dirty workaround:

```
    double prevMouseX = 0; // for storing  previos cursor position
    double prevMouseY = 0; //  

    private bool ZedGraphControl1MouseMoveEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

               PointF mousePt = new PointF( e.X, e.Y );
               GraphPane pane = sender.MasterPane.FindChartRect( mousePt );

               if ( pane != null ) 
               {
                  double x, y;
                  pane.ReverseTransform( mousePt, out x, out y );

                  if ((x == prevMouseX) && (y == prevMouseY))                      
                  {                                                                 
                      // Do nothing if the mouse position didn't change      
                      return false;                                      
                  }                                                      
                  else {                                                 
                      prevMouseX = x;                                   
                      prevMouseY = y;                                    
                  }                                                     

                  // Our code for toolTip goes here              

                  ...
```